# What Name (If Possible) Can I Use Over Docker Networks For Containers?

Tags: docker, networking

Using Docker with Rancher v1.6, and using phpMyAdmin inside of a container, with it's own stack creating a network called `db-admin`, and even when I add an alias to each of the MySQL containers I would like to be able to access, their alias does not resolve to the container IP address.

## Example

docker-compose.yml (Gogs):

```
version: '2'

services:
  gogs:
    image: gogs/gogs:latest
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    environment:
      RUN_CROND: true
      SOCAT_LINK: false # Being used inside of Rancher
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
      {{- if .Values.HOST_LABEL}}
      io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: ${HOST_LABEL}
      {{- end}}
      {{- if .Values.TRAEFIK_HOST}}
      traefik.enable: true
      ### Start SSH Segment
      traefik.ssh.frontend.entryPoints: ssh
      traefik.ssh.frontend.headers.forceSTSHeader: true
      traefik.ssh.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect: true
      traefik.ssh.frontend.headers.STSPreload: true
      traefik.ssh.frontend.headers.STSSeconds: 15552000
      traefik.ssh.frontend.rule: Host:${TRAEFIK_HOST}
      traefik.ssh.port: "22"
      ### End SSH Segment
      ### Start Web Segment
      traefik.web.frontend.entryPoints: http,https
      traefik.web.frontend.headers.forceSTSHeader: true
      traefik.web.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect: true
      traefik.web.frontend.headers.STSPreload: true
      traefik.web.frontend.headers.STSSeconds: 15552000
      traefik.web.frontend.rule: Host:${TRAEFIK_HOST}
      traefik.web.port: "3000"
      ### End Web Segment
      {{- else}}
      traefik.enable: false
      {{- end}}
    links:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - public-proxy
    ports:
      - "${SSH_PORT}:22"
      - "${WEB_PORT}:3000"
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro # Syncronize time of container with the host system
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro # Syncronize timezone of container with the host system
      - /RancherCattle/${DATA_DIR}/Data:/data
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: gogs # Will eventually rename this to "gogs_db"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASS}
      MYSQL_USER: gogs_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_USER_PASS}
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
      {{- if .Values.HOST_LABEL}}
      io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: ${HOST_LABEL}
      {{- end}}
    networks:
      db-admin:
        aliases:
          - gogs
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro # Syncronize time of container with the host system
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro # Syncronize timezone of container with the host system
      - /RancherCattle/${DATA_DIR}/Database:/var/lib/mysql

networks:
  db-admin:
    external: true
  public-proxy:
    external: true
```

(The SSH entrypoint does not work by the way... that's for another question XD)

docker-compose.yml (phpMyAdmin):

```
version: '2'

services:
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    environment:
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1 # Allows the user to specify any arbitrary server using address/hostname and port
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
      {{- if .Values.HOST_LABEL}}
      io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: ${HOST_LABEL}
      {{- end}}
      {{- if .Values.TRAEFIK_HOST}}
      traefik.enable: true
      ### Start Web Segment
      traefik.web.frontend.entryPoints: http,https
      traefik.web.frontend.headers.forceSTSHeader: true
      traefik.web.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect: true
      traefik.web.frontend.headers.STSPreload: true
      traefik.web.frontend.headers.STSSeconds: 15552000
      traefik.web.frontend.redirect.entryPoint: https
      traefik.web.frontend.redirect.permanent: true
      traefik.web.frontend.rule: Host:${TRAEFIK_HOST}
      traefik.web.port: "80"
      ### End Web Segment
      {{- else}}
      traefik.enable: false
      {{- end}}
    networks:
      - db-admin # Used to be able to make secure, direct connections to other services in other stacks
      - public-proxy # Used for the connection to the Traefik container for public access
    ports:
      - "${WEB_PORT}:80"
    restart: on-failure

networks:
  db-admin:
  public-proxy:
    external: true
```

I expected that I would simply be able to use "gogs" in the hostname field for phpMyAdmin to be able to reference the Gogs' MySQL container, but phpMyAdmin displays an error saying it is unable to resolve the name. I am able to use the IP address of the container (as shown by the Rancher v1.6 interface), but would have liked to have a "simpler" way of referencing it, if possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Service names are configured as a network alias by compose and swarm. If you have multiple matches for a DNS query, what you will see is a round robin between the various matches to each query.

Given that, you have a service name of gogs, and an alias for a mysql service as gogs. The result is that half of the DNS queries will resolve to the gogs service first, and the other half to the mysql service. This will result in unexpected behaviours.  You should change the name of your gogs service, or use a different name for the mysql alias.

Comment: After modifying the network alias to "gogs-db" [Shown Here](https://github.com/WilliamMiceli/Personal-Rancher-Catalog/blob/2ef6e46e73cf0b42439f9b156f71184a3c4fa5d8/templates/Gogs/0/docker-compose.yml) I still get the same "mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve" my phpMyAdmin...

Comment: @WilliamMiceli the containers need to be on the same docker network. Your database is on db-admin while the phpadmin is on a project specific db-admin. Define the phpadmin network to be external.

Comment: [Updated](https://github.com/WilliamMiceli/Personal-Rancher-Catalog/commit/684240b857e2ebff8f53a90b483b72afe27ef5be) the phpMyAdmin template, but still the same issue. Is it possible Rancher is interfering with this?

Comment: @WilliamMiceli not sure what else rancher is doing under the covers. You can try posting a `docker inspect` on each of the containers you are trying to communicate between.